# How accurately can huge factorials be calculated?

Tags: factorial

Given a number like $10^{20}!$, what can I, in a reasonable amount of time, figure out about it?  Can I figure out how many digits it has, and/or what the first digit is?  I found Striling's approximation, but I'm not aware of a realistic way to calculate something raised to the nth where n = $10^{20}$

Comment: I can tell you what the _last_ digit is... would you settle for the number of digits in the number of digits?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Um... Zero.

Comment: @Qiaochu: If that's the best that can be done, then yeah, I'd accept that.

Comment: On the subject of last digits, for any prime number $p$, you can compute $v_p(n!)$ the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization (called $p$-adic valuation) of $n!$  with the formula $$v_p(n!) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor$$ Computing the $5$-adic gives the number of zeros at the end. And if you can list the primes numbers up to $n$, then you can compute the full prime number factorization of $n!$. But I guess this is not interesting if you just want an estimate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stirling's approximation is very accurate for large numbers, so the number of digits is the integer part of

$$\log \left( \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \right) = n ( \log n - \log e) + \log \sqrt{2 \pi} + \frac{1}{2} \log n$$

where $n = 10^{20}$. The leading term in the above is $n \log n = 20 \cdot 10^{20} = 2 \cdot 10^{21}$, and any reasonable computer method for high-precision arithmetic will tell you the rest of the digits fairly easily if you want.

The leading digit can be calculated by computing the leading digit of $10^f$ where $f$ is the fractional part of the above. Again, this is relatively easy to do with any reasonable computer method for high-precision arithmetic (which I don't have access to at the moment, unfortunately, and I can't figure out how to get WolframAlpha to do this computation). By computing more digits of $f$ you can compute more leading digits (up to the accuracy of Stirling's formula).

If you really need to do this, it's worth noting that there are [additional terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) you can tack onto Stirling's formula for more accuracy.

Comment: The last term in your sum should be $\log \sqrt{n}$ or ${1 \over 2} \log n$.

Comment: Right you are, sir.

Comment: Should it be the integer part of the **ceiling** i.e. $ \lceil (expression) \rceil $ ? I am wondering how accurate Stirling is for around $100000000!$ particularly when the fractional part is close to $0$ or $ 1 $. BTW it is elegant expressed as $n ( \log n - \log e) + \frac{1}{2} ( \log n + \log 2 \pi)$

Answer (score 12):

Specifically, for large $x$, $$\ln(x!) = (\ln(x)-1) x + \frac{1}{2} \ln(x)+\frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi)+\frac{1}{12 x}-\frac{1}{360x^3}+\frac{1}{1260 x^5}-\frac{1}{1680 x^7} + \frac{t}{1188 x^9}$$ for some $t \in (0,1)$.   For $x = 10^{20}$, the uncertainty in the number (if calculated with a few hundred digits of precision) is about $10^{-183}$.
The result is that we can say $(10^{20})!$ has

$$1956570551809674817246$$

decimal digits, of which the first 100 are

$$1932849514310097712837014080536242806874079839409160617974884639778977403427259721535932189240606200...$$

Comment: For a discussion of how many digits you can extract from Stirling's approximation, see Problem 9.26 in Concrete Mathematics, by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik. In summary, you should be able to compute $n!$ with an error of about $n!/\left( \pi \sqrt{n} e^{2 \pi n} \right)$.